# IIS Node.js server download files relay error on Firefox and Chrome

Tags: asp.net, node.js, iis, networking, server

I'm using `IIS` 10 server as a gateway for Node.js server.

When client calls download files such as zip file, `IIS` server download `Node.js` server internally with `HTTP` protocol, and then it pass to client with `HTTPS`.

But in Chrome web browser, It shows error

> net::ERR_HTTP_1_1_REQUIRED with status 200, and when I try to download again it works well until I clear  the caches.

In Firefox, it returns status 200 too, but nothing's happen.

In Microsoft Edge and IE11 works well too.

I've set enough timeout and buffer size in `IIS`.

May Chrome and Firefox go wrong at `HTTPS` - `HTTP` connection or something else?

Comment: I solved it by myself. It just caused by miswrited IIS server C#.net code.

Comment: Care to elaborate?
I have the same problem. What was wrong with your code? Did you change some content type in the response or something?

Answer (score 0):

There may be some extensions in your Firefox and Chrome that can cause this error. This error means a browser extension blocked the request. The most common culprit is an ad blocker like AdBlock Plus. In short your requests to server have been blocked by an extension. so you can try to disable these extensions and try again.

Comment: You can also try to upgrade your browser to the latest version, this is the link of a similar case with the issue: [ERR_HTTP_1_1_REQUIRED](https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/issues/10753).

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the .NET Core team found a related issue and provided a workaround.
Perhaps the same can be applied with other frameworks.
https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/4398

Apparently, when doing an ajax request from a browser, it will sometimes send an OPTIONS request before the real request with a 204 status code which causes the problem.

For me, it seems to have solved my problem to return the file with a response content-type of "text/plain" instead of "application/octet-stream"

I'm not really sure why it works, it just does.